# Trying to conditionally change a file path in a windows batch script

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have a simple script that launches an XML file path in Notepad++

Unfortunately, the generated file path for some of the files is incorrect and I'm trying to compensate for it in the script (ideal fix is clearly to resolve the path issue but at the moment this is not an option).

Here is what I have, apologies for the code I'm very new to Batch Script...

```
set /p filePath= Enter file path: 
 if "%filePath%" == "1" goto xmlMenu
 else if "%filePath%" == "file://path/of/file/*/*/*/*/A/*.XML" 
 set filePath="file://path/of/file/*/*/*/*/B/*.XML"
goto openXML
```

I would like the filePath variable to inherit the rest of the path from the user input but at the moment its explicitly setting the path with the wildcards. There also seems to be a problem with the way I have stated the condition as it appears to set the path to /B/*.XML regardless of the else if condition.

Answer (score 0):

There are many errors, but as you say, youre new.

First, if the filepath you enter is "1" then you should arrive safely at xmlmenu.

The next line will generate an error because with an else clause,

- the If-true instruction must be (parenthesised)
- the `(` must occur on the same physical line as the `if`
- the sequence `) else (` must all be on the same physical line (which need not be the same as the `if`)

In any case, the `else` is redundant. If the condition is not true, the jump will not happen, hence the next statement line will be executed.

`if`...==... is true if the string on the left is identical to the sring on the right, hence you would need for the entered string to be absolutely identical to `file://path/of/file/*/*/*/*/A/*.XML` for the `if` to be true. The action-statment also must be on the same physical line as the `if`, so this is a second source of syntax errors.

the `set` is then executed, assigning that famous string (in quotes) to the variable `filepath`. And then we're off to `openxml`.

Note that `\` is a path separator in Windows; `/` is a switch-specifier.

Now - if you were to explain what you want to do - perhaps enter a filename which may be somewhere in a directory structure and if it's found then assign *what?* to the variable filepath. One or two examples would be a good idea.

---

This should get a usable system going. The numeric check is incomplete, but would be adequate. I've not made it bullet-proof against a user determined to break it...

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
:again
SET "filepath="
set /p filePath="Please enter filepath as yyyymmdd : "
IF NOT DEFINED filepath GOTO :EOF 
if "%filePath%" == "1" goto xmlMenu

:: test to see whether entered data is numeric
SET /a "filepath=%filepath%" 2>nul

IF %filepath%==0 echo invalid entry - numerics only, please&GOTO again
IF %filepath% lss 19800100 GOTO badymd
IF %filepath% gtr 20991231 GOTO badymd

SET filepath=\path\prefix\%filepath:~0,4%\%filepath:~4,2%\%filepath:~6,2%

:: This is just to show the filepath constructed
ECHO filepath is "%filepath%"

IF NOT exist "%filepath%\A\*.xml" ECHO "%filepath%\A\*.xml" does NOT exist&GOTO again
IF NOT exist "%filepath%\B\*.xml" ECHO "%filepath%\B\*.xml" does NOT exist&GOTO again
SET "filepath=%filepath%\B\*.xml"
goto openXML

:badymd
ECHO invalid entry - 4 digits FOR year, 2 FOR month an 2 FOR day, please
GOTO again

:xmlmenu
ECHO AT xmlmenu&GOTO :eof

:openxml
ECHO AT openxml with filepath="%filepath%"&GOTO :eof

GOTO :EOF
```

Obviously, change the path prefix to suit.

For an input of `20140220`, the path `....\2014\02\20` would be constructed. Then there's a check for  and `this +\B\*.xml` - I can only presume both must exist to proceed to `openxml`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, the reason I'm trying to use wildcards is that the /*/*/*/*/ folders are date specific with the 'A' folder as a sub-directory. All I need is for the path to inherit from the user input, e.g. path/to/file/2014/02/18/A/file.xml and then change it to /b/file.xml